# JavaScript - Meaning of this Higher Order Function

Tags: javascript, function, higher-order-functions

first of all sorry if I'm not posting on the right place or if there's already a duplicate, but i don't know what to call this or how to search for it.

Can someone please explain to me what does the following code mean:

```
function noisy(f) {
  return function(arg) {
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    var val = f(arg);
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    return val;
  };
}
noisy(Boolean)(0);
// → calling with 0
// → called with 0 - got false
```

Why do I need to have (Boolean) after the function call ?

```
noisy(Boolean)(0);
```

What do i call this type of function call ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"Why do I need to have (Boolean) after the function call ?"* It's not *after* the function call. `noisy(Boolean)` *is* the function call. You are calling `noisy` passing `Boolean` as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is tricky stuff. `(Boolean)` might throw you off here, but really it's just a regular old parameter. You could replace `Boolean` with any function, like `doStuff`, and it'd still work.

And yes, as you pointed out, this is a duplicate question. You're looking at something called "closure." Here's a fantastic answer from StackOverflow:

[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helped me a lot, and i even discovered Im still not good enough at closures or else i would have known it was one.

Comment: After reading the link you posted, Example 6 actually explains my doubt. Thanks a lot really!

Comment: You're welcome! Perhaps I should also clarify that you are, in fact, also dealing with [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) (see link for simple definition) in your example. An example of a higher-order function is a [callback function](http://www.learn-js.org/en/Callbacks) (see link for simple explanation).

Comment: I knew it was a Higher Order Function because I'm reading Eloquent JavaScript and that's the Chapter name ahahah, thanks anyway. I still have a lot of doubts about JavaScript but i wan't to learn every little intricacy about it.

Answer (score 2):

"noisy" is a function that returns a function if you call it.

By passing `Boolean` into the function, `Boolean` is called like `Boolean(0)` which results in `false` since 0 is a falsy value.

`Boolean` is just a constructor that you can use to create booleans or to cast any value to a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a function `noisy(...)` which is returning another function which it constructs using information from its parameters.  The *function call* `noisy(Boolean)(0);` is actually two function calls and could (maybe should) be written as:

```
var noisyFunction = noisy(Boolean)
noisyFunction(0)
```

The fact that `noisy()` takes a function (`Boolean` is a function [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean)).  Has no real effect on the syntax being used here, it could take no arguments, or something less zany.

Your selection of the higher-order-functions tag really kind of sums it up.  This is an example of programming with them.  The fact that the value `f` is available to `noisyFunction` after `noisy` returns is the result of a closure ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)).  Some programmers might then describe this as, "using a closure", but it is not specific to the pattern shown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, similarly to the other answer you helped me a lot thanks for explaining to me that i could call the same function in multiple ways, now it really looks like the type of closures i'm used to seeing!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an `f` - it could be anything else than the `Boolean` function. Try

```
const increment = x => x+1;
const noisyInc = noisy(increment);
console.log(noisyInc(1));
```

In your original code, the intermediate variable is omitted - just like I could've written `noisy(increment)(1)` here.

Comment: For what it's worth, it *could* be anything else. Using `Boolean` also works because `Boolean` will just convert (cast) values into a boolean (and return) when you use it without `new`.

Comment: @towerofnix Yes, that's what `Boolean` does.